# Scroll down Landing page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a landing page on which users have to scroll down to then display the first page of the site.

Similar to this: http://www.georgeandharrison.nl/

As you can see, the nav bar is hidden until you scroll past a certain point. I've tried googling about for it, but in all fairness, i have no idea what this technique is called.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: [Link](http://stickyjs.com/)

The header will scroll down at a certain point

Comment: Hmm unfortunately no. You see how the G&H site has the coloured landing page with the animated text on? Then when you scroll it parralax scrolls onto the first page? It's that landing and scrolling i want to achieve.

Comment: you can achieve the same result with the use of this